# how to get the title attributes in my lvrow in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

im trying to get the title in `function getProj(lvrow)`. but i dont know whats wrong in my javascript.

heres my javascript

```
function getProj(lvrow){ 
    var btnhd = document.getElementById("hdField");
    btnhd.value = $(lvrow).data("title") // in this part the program always stop
    document.getElementById("getProj").click();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have JQuery in the second line of your function?

Comment: have you checked if the developer's console throws any errors?

Comment: oh! is that a jquery. i dont know. this is my first time to use a javascript.

Comment: change it to `btnhd.value = lvrow.title` if your `lvrow` is an html node

Comment: i forget to tell "lvrow" is a listview row

Comment: read my comment under Mr.7 answer

Comment: Thanks alex. it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i understood, **lvrow** is your project object and it has `title` property.

```
function getProj(lvrow){ 
    var btnhd = document.getElementById("hdField");
    btnhd.value = lvrow.title;
    document.getElementById("getProj").click();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: note: this will work only if `lvrow` is a DOM element and not class or id. otherwise you can use `document.getElementById("yourid").title` instead

Answer (score 1):

HTML DOM title Property:

```js
var titleAttr = document.getElementById('myAbbr').title;
console.log(titleAttr);
```

```html
<p>
  <abbr id="myAbbr" title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.
</p>
```

In your function, once you get the element by `id`, you can directly access to its property `title`:

```
function getProj(lvrow) {
    var btnhd = document.getElementById("hdField");
    document.getElementById("getProj").click();

    // Element's property title
    console.log(btnhd.title);
}
```

Comment: i need to get the title attributes in (lvrow).